Mould issue in underground basement
I have a basement that I use as studio that is part of a house that is pretty old (built around 1948), and I have a mould issue in it, as you can see from the following photos:


The issue appears on the side of the basement that is underground. Usually, there are 2 big bookshelves that cover most of the wall, but not all it, nevertheless the mould is everywhere on it.
I have once asked for a quote to fix the issue from a company that told me that the issue could be fixed by injecting some substance in the wall. However, since they were asking 10,000 euro to do it, I had to show them the door...
The situation has now become more serious as not only I am using it as my studio, but I will have to start to sleep in it as well...
For the moment, I have used a biocide to kill the mould, but my aim is to make the room safe for me to sleep and work in it.
What do you suggest me to do?

That's a mold problem only because you have a water infiltration problem.  The latter is the one you need to solve first.
